# How to extract from string all words between double quotes using SED

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use a regexp, like

```
.*?"([^"]+).*?"/g
```

to extract all words between double quotes from string.
For example from:

> < Header param1="1" param2="2" param3="" param4="" param5=5 param6="6"
>   >

I would like to get:

> 1 2 6

Yes, I know that I can use grep, but it is necessary do it by sed

Comment: What is the problem with your current regex?

Comment: `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions by default where `+` is literal, some flavors support using `-r` or `-E` to enable Extended Regular Expressions which will treat `+` as a metacharacter.

Comment: Try `"\([^"]*\)"`. Parens usually need escaping on many Linux flavors.

Comment: @andlrc. You can also often use `\+` to indicate the meta character.

Comment: No sed, no grep. Use an XML-aware tool.

Comment: @choroba. OP explicitly requires sed and the sample is just that.

Comment: I literally don't think you can do this with just `sed` unless you jump through hoops with a pipe. `sed`, unlike `grep`, does not have an option to print just the matching part of a line. Without `/g`, you could do `^.*expr.*$`, but that will only get you a single match.

Comment: That being said, here is something that will get you pretty close: `sed -n 's/[^"]\+"\([^"]*\)"/\1\n/gp' <<< '< Header param1="1" param2="2" param3="" param4="" param5=5 param6="6" >'`. The result is `1 2    6 >`. This will match the empty strings (as well as the portion after the last quote for some reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BRE or ERE than can do what you want so it can't be done in one regexp with sed. You CAN do this in sed instead if that's acceptable:

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$//g; s/"[^"]+"/ /g; s/ +/ /g' file
1 2 6
```